# Query weekly data (Monday to Sunday) and avoid overlapping year dates

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a simple SQL query. I'm trying to get data grouped by weeks of the year, based on Monday to Sunday. The DATEPART function seems to make this easily doable. But I run into a problem. I get overlapping year dates.

For example, 01/01/23 is technically 2023, but it's part of the last week of 2022. The numbers for that day are included in the table that is returned.

Here's a sample of what I'm talking about.

[image]

```
SELECT DATEPART(WEEK, responsedate) AS week_number,
       CAST(MIN(responsedate) AS DATE) AS from_date,
       CAST(MAX(responsedate) AS DATE) AS to_date,
       (COUNT(CASE WHEN ov_rating >= 8 THEN 1 END) * 100.0 / NULLIF(COUNT(ov_rating), 0)) AS overall_rating,
       (COUNT(CASE WHEN recommend >= 9 THEN 1 END) * 100.0 / NULLIF(COUNT(recommend), 0)) -
       (COUNT(CASE WHEN recommend BETWEEN 1 AND 6 THEN 1 END) * 100.0 / NULLIF(COUNT(recommend), 0)) AS recommend_score
FROM survey
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM responsedate) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM GETDATE())
AND responsedate <= GETDATE()
GROUP BY DATEPART(WEEK, responsedate)
ORDER BY from_date
```

Comment: `...AND to_date > from_date...`?

Comment: The question is if 01/01/2023 belongs to your data set of week grouped by year for the year 2023. It might belong the the year 2022, because it's in week 52

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `ISOYEAR` (not `YEAR`) together with `WEEK`. YEAR is the year the day actually belongs to, but ISOYEAR is the year of the *whole week*.

e.g. 2023-01-01 (`YEAR=2023`) was a Sunday, and it belongs to the week `2022-52` that started on the Monday before (2022-12-26 with `ISOYEAR=2022`, `WEEK=52`).

See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html:

> `WEEK` The number of the ISO 8601 week-numbering week of the year. By definition, ISO weeks start on Mondays and the first week of a year contains January 4 of that year. In other words, the first Thursday of a year is in week 1 of that year.

And:

> It's recommended to use the `isoyear` field together with `week` to get consistent results.